# Reading from the file with cyrillic not working (size of input = 0)

Tags: c++, file, io

File `файл.txt` (saved using UTF-8):

```
Привет
```

File `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    fstream f("файл.txt", ios::in);
    string s;
    f >> s;
    cout << s.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

I could understand that the output will be different (different encoding) but there isn't any output.

Comment: Try specifying the file with a wide string `L"файл.txt"`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I renamed `файл.txt` for `file.txt` and the problem was solved